# Shell command "find -name $variable" not working as expected

Tags: bash, shell

Sorry, I am new to bash. I have a fairly simple script that is something like the below:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep file.txt | awk '{print $2}' | while read -r line; do
        log "$line"
        log "find path/to/csv -name $line"
        command=$(find path/to/csv -name $line)
        log "$command"
done
}
```

What I am trying to do is grab the second field for every line in the file.txt file, pipe it to the line variable and then use that to find any csv file in the /path/to/csv directory with a name that matches any name in file.txt. This isn't working so I have stripped it down to be as simple as I can.

When I use the $line variable in the log command, the log file brings the second field for every line as expected. However when I use the $line variable with the find command, it is not working and the log shows a blank output.

```
20200702-16h-12m-33s filename*.csv
20200702-16h-12m-33s find path/to/csv -name filename*.csv
20200702-16h-12m-33s
```

Just wondering if I need to anything to my $line variable within the find command? I have tried:

```
$line
"$line"
"*line*"
${line}
{$line}
```

Any help would be massively appreciated

Comment: Include a [mre] please

Comment: Can you give examples of the file contents and the files you're trying to match?

Comment: `-name "$variable"` -- quotes matter. (Curly braces don't).

Comment: BTW, I would strongly suggest using `bash -x yourscript` to run the script with individual commands it runs logged. If your input file has DOS instead of UNIX newlines and the 2nd column is the last one, for example, that would explain `find` not finding anything.

Comment: ...also, generally, `grep foo file.txt | awk { print $2 }` is unnecessary. `awk '/foo/ { print $2 }'` does both steps (searching for lines that contain `foo`, and printing the 2nd column) at once.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store the command in a variable.
That is, don't do this: `command=$(find path/to/csv -name $line)`
Instead just store the "find" arguments in an array and then the run find command with it.
So, in your case, it would be something like this:

```
args=(path/to/csv -name "$line")
find "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: The OP's original code successfully stores the _results_ of calling `find` in the variable `command`. Is your interpretation that that's not what they meant to do? Also, even in an array, it needs to be `-name "$line"` to prevent the value from being string-split and globbed before `find` sees it.

Comment: ...that is to say, if `line='*.txt'`, then you'll end up with something like `args=( path/to/csv -name a.txt b.txt c.txt )` assigned, if there are three text files in the current directory when this code is invoked. Since `-name` only expects _one_ argument to follow it, this results in an error from `find`.